# How do I prevented the hackers (secret intel) manipulating my terminal again

Tags: terminal, security, bash, sudo

**How do I prevented the hackers manipulating my terminal again so that my terminal works correct again?**

Here in the Netherlands we perform cybertest at the company where we work and the attacks are performed by the Dutch goverment AIVD (the group who also caught the Fancy Bear hackers). A hacker has root access on my MacBook Air. How do I know that(it was announced that we would get hacked)? The hacker is capable of running the:

```
sudo hostname 192
```

The hacker explicitly ran the command above. The hacker also manipulates my bash. I executed the command-line

```
sudo dscl . list /Users | grep -v '^_'
```

and see four users:

- daemon
- nobody
- jen
- Root

I don’t know where to look at since my bash is manipulated. In my terminal only the commands that I performed two days ago are shown. The commands of yesterday and today are not shown. Even if I perform

Example:

```
Last login: Mon Aug 27 17:37:19 on ttys001
192:~ jen$ history -c
192:~ jen$ history -w

Last login: Mon Aug 27 17:38:49 on ttys002
192:~ jen$ history 
    1  nano doc.txt
    2  cat doc.txt
```

**How do I prevented the hackers manipulating my terminal again so that my terminal works correct again?**

*I am not victim of social engineering, I did not opened any links or files via mail or downloaded some application. I use the laptop only to work on highly confidential stuff.
I only uses software delivered by Mac on my system. (I did not download any files via mail and I don't use any browser) I use this laptop to write mails only(Nothing more).*

Comment: `A hacker penetrated in my system and has root access. How do I know that? ` The two statements are contradictory. Please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/334845/edit) the question and clarify.

Comment: Ah the old *hack your computer and do absolutely nothing waiting to be found out by the owner*.

Comment: It will help if you can add an explanation as to what makes you think a hacker ran the command `/Volumes/UBUNTU\ 16_0/ubuntu ; exit;` to unmount the USB stick.

Comment: That command doesn't eject or unmount anything.

Comment: I tried it myself and 192:~ jen$ /Volumes/UBUNTU\ 16_0/ubuntu ; exit;
logout
[Process completed] I don't know what it does.

Comment: What's your output of the following command `cat /Volumes/UBUNTU\ 16_0/ubuntu`

Comment: Sometimes my Macbook Pro's hostname also changes to 192. I think it's just parsing the IP address as a domain and then grabbing the first "segment" as your hostname.

Comment: ***Hold up a minute here.***  In the comments (here and below) and in chat, there are three different perpetrators:  a friend, a government agency, and now a training exercise at work.  **Important question:  did you happen to find a USB drive somewhere and then insert it into your machine?  Or... did you click on an email asking you to reset your password, or enter credentials?**

Comment: I thought it was friend. But we received an mail that it was our government and in the email they mail they mailed two letters of my password en the last letter. The training exercise is performed by our government. The USB stick is my own usb.

Comment: Jennifer, after perusing the questions you have asked on StackExchange I have a better idea of the background context of your situation.  I believe that you believe that your mac is compromised.  This might actually be the case -- it is a common strategy for an infiltrator to attempt to cover their tracks -- the .bash_history file was apparently deleted in order to attempt to leave no command history log.  Read the Readme.md on my fork of your gitub repo -- it has my email address.  We should take our conversation to email.  F.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you have sprung to an incorrect conclusion - that your Mac was hacked.

The most likely cause of "unwanted" or "surprising" host name changes is that your DHCP server gave your computer a new hostname. The DHCP server could be a router/modem in your own house, a system at your ISP or indeed hardware at anywhere you have connected to a WiFi network (such as a coffee shop, school or whatever).

Removing sudo rights from yours won't help this problem, as the DHCP client on your Mac will still be able to change your hostname.

Comment: The hackers also runned the command  to remove my usb stick>>
   76  sudo tcpdump
   77  /Volumes/UBUNTU\ 16_0/ubuntu ; exit;
>>

Answer (score 4):

**There is no evidence that you were hacked.**

The four users that you are listed don't have "root" access per se and they are all valid accounts:

- `daemon` - a user to handle the background processes that aren't tied to a specific user, the user `daemon` is given those processes.  This is how you can have your Mac turned on, nobody logged in and processes still run.
- `nobody` - this is another user that gets assigned processes (like `httpd`) and has *very* limited access to the system.  Even if someone were to hack it, is exposure would be limited.
- `jen` - I'm assuming this is you (SE username is "jennifer ruurs").  If you're an admin  user, you have `sudo` rights which gives you root access
- `root` - this the root account.  This account *needs* root access especially if you boot into Single User mode for diagnostics or repairs.

The command you mentioned only *temporarily* changes the hostname of your computer.

```
sudo hostname 192
```

This only happens if and only if, the user/group it logged in as is in the `/etc/sudoers` file and they either had the password or `/etc/sudoers` is configured for no password authentication (very insecure and not default macOS setting).

All of the users above, with the exception of `jen`, *cannot* (by default) access your computer remotely.  So, if you are convinced that you were "hacked", you need to either find the *user* account that grants them access or if it was your account, mitigate your risk, change your password.

Comment: The hackers runned the command 
   77  /Volumes/UBUNTU\ 16_0/ubuntu ; exit; in my terminal to unmount my usb stick

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: I saw this command in my terminal.Thank you for your answer how do if find the account that grants them the access?

Comment: The `dscl` command in your orig question lists the users.  Which one(s) don't you recognize?  Secondly, what user context did the hostname and command run as?  If it was you, then change your password.

Comment: I was logged on as jen. The commands where run via my account but they are also manipulating my bash. So I am not capable of seeing which commands they run.

Comment: *The commands where run via my account but they are also manipulating my bash.*  1)  *How* do you know this and 2) did you change your password like I advised?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82301/discussion-between-jennifer-ruurs-and-allan).

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the title directly:

## You cannot.

**Wipe everything, reinstall macOS and restore files from backup (*not* from the infected machine).**

For completeness, it's worth mentioning there exist attacks that e.g. infect the firmware of storage devices, necessitating the entire hardware to be destroyed to ensure 100% safety. Unless you have reason to believe you are being personally targeted by a government, though, this isn't a realistic worry - by contrast, infecting any part of the data actually stored on disk is orders of magnitude easier and a very realistic threat. Even if you were just the victim of an automated, untargeted attack, wiping everything is a necessary precaution.

#### Why?

If an attacker has root access, they can, among other things, replace *any* binary with their own version that can do whatever they like, meaning that you cannot trust *anything* on your system anymore. **Quite literally anything** you try to do might end up doing something **completely different**. If the hacker wanted, they might make `cat` return doctored version of files to e.g. hide log entries showing unwanted activity; `ls` could fail to show files added by the hacker; any text editor could pretend to save what you write but actually silently ignore your edits, etc., etc.

#### Can't I at least keep my files? I have things that were backed up a while ago/aren't backed up at all

The reason you don't want to copy your files over is that there are plenty of non-executable file types that can exploit some vulnerability or other and reinfect your system. Compressed archives of various types and PDFs are common carriers, but by no means the only danger. You're *probably* safe copying over a plaintext, non-executable text file (remember to not use the compromised OS to do that, though), but remember that the attacer could have changed absolutely anything in absolutely any way they wanted,so treat everything like you would treat a random file accidentally downloaded from a shady website.

## More realistically...

You also have to think about *why* the hacker would do something like that. Replacing `cat` and `ls` with malicious versions is entirely possible, but making the output sophisticated enough to fool you into thinking everything's fine is much more complex. If the hacker just wanted to spy on you, they'd install a keylogger and leave everything else alone. If they wanted to use your machine in a botnet, they'd install the necessary software and leave everything else alone. If they wanted *your* money specifically, they'd have installed ransomware, and you'd know that already.

None of the above cases involve editing your bash history, or changing the hostname of your machine. A keylogger or similar rootkit can be made virtually undetectable. So while a root attacker *can* do anything, usually that means you'll never be able to guess they're there, except by e.g. observing your load being higher than usual when your compromised machine participated in a botnet. Or if they didn't mind you knowing they were in, it's much, much easier to just lock a user out (e.g. by changing the account password) than mess with the bash history. (Or, again, ransomware.)

## So what happened here and what should you do?

The other answers already describe what I personally agree is the most probable scenario: a few flukes, like the DHCP server changing your hostname. In which case you're uncompromised and fine.
The alternative is that someone manually broke into your machine, and is either clumsily trying to hide it, or intentionally messing with you. This could be a family member, or coworker, or other acquiantance; perhaps they might have shoulder-surfed your password. *If* that the case *and* you're certain they didn't install any rootkits or keyloggers in the meantime, then just changing the relevant passwords (root, and your user's) should be enough. But you really can't know what they did or didn't do, and once you already have root access it's utterly trivial to install a ready-made malware package - so if you truly believe someone gained unauthorized root access, then, as explained above, wipe everything.

Comment: I just heard that it was a training at work and that I failed. No one had physically access to the laptop. Read how my bash is manipulated. The command sudo hostname was shown in my terminal. the part of the usb popping up to.

Comment: Oh, if it was an artifical scenario (for training) that explains the unusual actions. I'm not sure what kind of training it is, but most of my answer still applies for a realistic scenario: if you know someone has root access to your account, EVERYTHING is off the table. If they would expect you to do something different for training, then it's bad training. In this case, if you kept everything updated and didn't do anything to expose yourself to vulnerabilities (like running old/unsafe software), you might have fallen victim to a social engineering attack. It's hard to say without more info.

Comment: I am not a victim of social engineering and I have no old software. I only uses software delivered by Mac on my system.